# C int to char not printing out using char format

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out the digits of an integer using the char format specifier.

This is what I currently have

```
    //counter = arbitrary int
    while (counter > 0) {
            char c = (char)(counter % 10);
            printf("%c", c);
            counter/=10;
        }
```

This just prints out blank but if I change the format specifier to int but leave the type cast, it'll print the correct value. Something like this

```
   char c = (char)(counter % 10);
   printf("%d", c);
```

Any ideas why this isn't printing when I use the char format specifier?

Comment: `(counter % 10)` --> `(counter % 10 + '0')`

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked

Comment: It is printing, but character code `1` is also known as Control-A, `2` as Control-B, etc.  7 might generate a noise; 8 is backspace; 9 is tab.  They're all control characters with no visible representation by default.

Comment: @VincentLe You are confusing numbers (like zero or four) with representations of numbers like "0" and "4". You are expecting `printf("%c", c)` to print out the digit representing the numeric value of c. But that's not what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` is for printing a character, not a number. If you want to print a number, you *should* use `%d`. The reason it works for `char` is because `char` is implicitly promoted to `int` when you pass it as an argument to a variadic function.

If `c` contained `'A'`, and you used `%c` to format it, you would get the letter ‘A’, but if you used `%d`, you would get its integer value, e.g. 65.

If you absolutely must use `%c`, you can add the value of `'0'` to the character before printing, e.g.L

```
printf("%c", c + '0');
```

Comment: Yeah, I know `%c` is for character, but I have to use the character specifier

Comment: @VincentLe: You need to mention this in your post so people don't waste time providing irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` can be used in this context as `printf("%c",c+'0')` where `+'0'` will turn it into the integer equivalent of `c`.

Comment: Where `+'0'` will provide the *equivalent ASCII character value for the number*... See: [**ASCII Table.com**](http://www.asciitable.com).

Comment: The character value in whatever the execution character set is, in fact, whether it's ASCII or not.